403 Forbidden on LocalHost?
I'm hosting a React localhost at port 3001, and trying to fetch from localhost5000. However, i keep encountering a 403 Forbidden error, even though its on my own computer. I'm completely lost on how to fix this. I've tried to check on the localhost myself by putting it into Edge, but I still get a 403 Forbidden error. I know that pytrends works, because I try it without FastAPI and can get data from it.
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
  const [score, setScore] = useState(null);
  const [last5Entries, setLast5Entries] = useState();

  const calculateScore = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/pytrends", { 'text': inputText });
      console.log(response);
      const interest = response.data.interest; //TO BE IMPLEMENTED (get score somehow)
      const score = response.score;
      setScore(score);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error('Error calculating niche score:', error);
    }
  }

  return (
    #some html 
  );
};

export default App;

@app.post("/pytrends")
async def trend_data(request: Request):
    pytrends = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)
    # Get user input as a list
    kw_list = request.json()['text']#gets JSON and extracts the input keyword

    pytrends.build_payload(kw_list, cat=0, timeframe='today 12-m', geo='', gprop='')  # Builds payload for keyword and interest over the last 12 months
    data = pytrends.interest_over_time()  # Returns pandas.DataFrame

    # Calculate the niche score by summing the 'score' column
    niche_score = data[kw_list[0]].sum()

    # Create a dictionary with the interest and score
    data_dict = {"interest": kw_list[0], "score": niche_score}

    # Add the current row to the DataFrame
    global df
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([data_dict])], ignore_index=True)

    return {"score": niche_score}```




Check this answer.

Does this answer your question?

Related answers can be found here , as well as here and here

This is likely a CORS issue: your FastAPI app by default will tell your browser not to accept requests from localhost:3000.
You can fix this by adding:
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


(Referenced from https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/)
